# Php : Modify multi-dimension array values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
<?php

//Here is my array in serialized form:

$array_serial = 'a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:19:"products.php?la=men";s:6:"otitle";s:3:"Men";s:6:"utitle";s:3:"Men";s:4:"ttip";s:3:"Men";}s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:35:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing";s:6:"otitle";s:12:"All Clothing";s:6:"utitle";s:12:"All Clothing";s:4:"ttip";s:18:"Men : All Clothing";}s:8:"children";a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:63:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear";s:6:"otitle";s:22:"Winter & Seasonal Wear";s:6:"utitle";s:22:"Winter & Seasonal Wear";s:4:"ttip";s:43:"Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear";}s:8:"children";a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:74:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Jackets";s:6:"otitle";s:7:"Jackets";s:6:"utitle";s:7:"Jackets";s:4:"ttip";s:53:"Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Jackets";}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:80:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Thermal-Pants";s:6:"otitle";s:13:"Thermal Pants";s:6:"utitle";s:13:"Thermal Pants";s:4:"ttip";s:59:"Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Thermal Pants";}}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:84:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Suits-AnD-Blazers";s:6:"otitle";s:15:"Suits & Blazers";s:6:"utitle";s:15:"Suits & Blazers";s:4:"ttip";s:61:"Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Suits & Blazers";}s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:95:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Suits-AnD-Blazers&le=Blazers";s:6:"otitle";s:7:"Blazers";s:6:"utitle";s:7:"Blazers";s:4:"ttip";s:71:"Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Suits & Blazers : Blazers";}}}}}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:44:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Other";s:6:"otitle";s:5:"Other";s:6:"utitle";s:5:"Other";s:4:"ttip";s:26:"Men : All Clothing : Other";}}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:45:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Shirts";s:6:"otitle";s:6:"Shirts";s:6:"utitle";s:6:"Shirts";s:4:"ttip";s:27:"Men : All Clothing : Shirts";}s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:62:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Shirts&ld=Formal-Shirts";s:6:"otitle";s:13:"Formal Shirts";s:6:"utitle";s:13:"Formal Shirts";s:4:"ttip";s:43:"Men : All Clothing : Shirts : Formal Shirts";}}}}i:3;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:50:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear";s:6:"otitle";s:11:"Sports Wear";s:6:"utitle";s:11:"Sports Wear";s:4:"ttip";s:32:"Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear";}s:8:"children";a:4:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:65:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Track-Pants";s:6:"otitle";s:11:"Track Pants";s:6:"utitle";s:11:"Track Pants";s:4:"ttip";s:46:"Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Track Pants";}}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:60:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Shorts";s:6:"otitle";s:6:"Shorts";s:6:"utitle";s:6:"Shorts";s:4:"ttip";s:41:"Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Shorts";}s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:70:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Shorts&le=Sports";s:6:"otitle";s:6:"Sports";s:6:"utitle";s:6:"Sports";s:4:"ttip";s:50:"Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Shorts : Sports";}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:69:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Shorts&le=Other";s:6:"otitle";s:5:"Other";s:6:"utitle";s:5:"Other";s:4:"ttip";s:49:"Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Shorts : Other";}}}}i:2;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:65:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=TDaShShirts";s:6:"otitle";s:8:"T-Shirts";s:6:"utitle";s:8:"T-Shirts";s:4:"ttip";s:43:"Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : T-Shirts";}}i:3;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:59:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Other";s:6:"otitle";s:5:"Other";s:6:"utitle";s:5:"Other";s:4:"ttip";s:40:"Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Other";}}}}i:4;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:44:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Jeans";s:6:"otitle";s:5:"Jeans";s:6:"utitle";s:5:"Jeans";s:4:"ttip";s:26:"Men : All Clothing : Jeans";}}}}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:31:"products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear";s:6:"otitle";s:8:"Footwear";s:6:"utitle";s:8:"Footwear";s:4:"ttip";s:14:"Men : Footwear";}s:8:"children";a:4:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:47:"products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Casual-Shoes";s:6:"otitle";s:12:"Casual Shoes";s:6:"utitle";s:12:"Casual Shoes";s:4:"ttip";s:29:"Men : Footwear : Casual Shoes";}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:41:"products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Sports";s:6:"otitle";s:6:"Sports";s:6:"utitle";s:6:"Sports";s:4:"ttip";s:23:"Men : Footwear : Sports";}}i:2;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:55:"products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Sandals-and-Floaters";s:6:"otitle";s:20:"Sandals and Floaters";s:6:"utitle";s:20:"Sandals and Floaters";s:4:"ttip";s:37:"Men : Footwear : Sandals and Floaters";}}i:3;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:56:"products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Slippers-and-FlipFlop";s:6:"otitle";s:21:"Slippers and FlipFlop";s:6:"utitle";s:21:"Slippers and FlipFlop";s:4:"ttip";s:38:"Men : Footwear : Slippers and FlipFlop";}}}}}}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:21:"products.php?la=women";s:6:"otitle";s:5:"Women";s:6:"utitle";s:5:"Women";s:4:"ttip";s:5:"Women";}s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:36:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear";s:6:"otitle";s:11:"Ethnic Wear";s:6:"utitle";s:11:"Ethnic Wear";s:4:"ttip";s:19:"Women : Ethnic Wear";}s:8:"children";a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:58:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Kurtas-AnD-Kurties";s:6:"otitle";s:16:"Kurtas & Kurties";s:6:"utitle";s:16:"Kurtas & Kurties";s:4:"ttip";s:38:"Women : Ethnic Wear : Kurtas & Kurties";}s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:69:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Kurtas-AnD-Kurties&ld=Kurties";s:6:"otitle";s:7:"Kurties";s:6:"utitle";s:7:"Kurties";s:4:"ttip";s:48:"Women : Ethnic Wear : Kurtas & Kurties : Kurties";}}}}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:54:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms";s:6:"otitle";s:14:"Ethnic Bottoms";s:6:"utitle";s:14:"Ethnic Bottoms";s:4:"ttip";s:36:"Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms";}s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:78:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Patialas-AnD-Salwars";s:6:"otitle";s:18:"Patialas & Salwars";s:6:"utitle";s:18:"Patialas & Salwars";s:4:"ttip";s:57:"Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Patialas & Salwars";}s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:90:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Patialas-AnD-Salwars&le=Patialas";s:6:"otitle";s:8:"Patialas";s:6:"utitle";s:8:"Patialas";s:4:"ttip";s:68:"Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Patialas & Salwars : Patialas";}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:89:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Patialas-AnD-Salwars&le=Salwars";s:6:"otitle";s:7:"Salwars";s:6:"utitle";s:7:"Salwars";s:4:"ttip";s:67:"Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Patialas & Salwars : Salwars";}}}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:69:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Harem-Pants";s:6:"otitle";s:11:"Harem Pants";s:6:"utitle";s:11:"Harem Pants";s:4:"ttip";s:50:"Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Harem Pants";}}}}i:2;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:45:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Other";s:6:"otitle";s:5:"Other";s:6:"utitle";s:5:"Other";s:4:"ttip";s:27:"Women : Ethnic Wear : Other";}}}}}}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:23:"products.php?la=eyewear";s:6:"otitle";s:7:"Eyewear";s:6:"utitle";s:7:"Eyewear";s:4:"ttip";s:7:"Eyewear";}s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:42:"products.php?la=eyewear&lb=Spectacle-Frame";s:6:"otitle";s:15:"Spectacle Frame";s:6:"utitle";s:15:"Spectacle Frame";s:4:"ttip";s:25:"Eyewear : Spectacle Frame";}}}}i:3;a:1:{s:2:"id";a:4:{s:3:"url";s:23:"products.php?la=watches";s:6:"otitle";s:7:"Watches";s:6:"utitle";s:7:"Watches";s:4:"ttip";s:7:"Watches";}}}';




//Here is my code to view "otitle" in a input type

function get_menu_list($selected_menus)
{

    if($selected_menus != null){
    foreach($selected_menus as $menu_level_1)
    {

        $title = implode("///",$menu_level_1['id']);

        echo '
            <li class="dd-item">
                <div class="dd-handle">
                    <input type="text" name="otitle[]" value="'.$menu_level_1['id']['otitle'].'" />
                </div>
        ';

        if(isset($menu_level_1['children']))
        {
            echo '<ol class="dd-list">';

            foreach($menu_level_1['children'] as $menu_level_2)
            {

                $title_level_2 = implode("///",$menu_level_2['id']);

                echo '
                    <li class="dd-item">
                        <div class="dd-handle">
                            <input type="text" name="otitle[]" value="'.$menu_level_2['id']['otitle'].'" />
                    </div>
                    ';

                if(isset($menu_level_2['children']))
                {
                    echo '<ol class="dd-list">';

                    foreach($menu_level_2['children'] as $menu_level_3)
                    {

                        $title_level_3 = implode("///",$menu_level_3['id']);

                        echo '
                            <li class="dd-item">
                              <div class="dd-handle">
                                <input type="text" name="otitle[]" value="'.$menu_level_3['id']['otitle'].'" />
                              </div>
                          ';

                        if(isset($menu_level_3['children']))
                        {
                            echo '<ol class="dd-list">';

                            foreach($menu_level_3['children'] as $menu_level_4)
                            {
                                $title_level_4 = implode("///",$menu_level_4['id']);

                                    echo '
                                        <li class="dd-item">
                                          <div class="dd-handle">
                                            <input type="text" name="otitle[]" value="'.$menu_level_4['id']['otitle'].'" />
                                          </div>
                                      ';

                                if(isset($menu_level_4['children']))
                                {
                                    echo '<ol class="dd-list">';

                                    foreach($menu_level_4['children'] as $menu_level_5)
                                    {
                                        $title_level_5 = implode("///",$menu_level_5['id']);

                                        echo '
                                            <li class="dd-item">
                                              <div class="dd-handle">
                                                <input type="text" name="otitle[]" value="'.$menu_level_5['id']['otitle'].'" />
                                              </div>
                                            </li>
                                          ';
                                    }

                                    echo "</ol>";
                                }

                                echo '</li>';
                            }

                            echo "</ol>";

                        }

                        echo '</li>';

                    }

                    echo "</ol>";
                }

                echo '</li>';

            }

            echo '</ol>';
        }

        echo '</li>';

    }

    }//end if
    else
    return null;    
}


$array_unserial = unserialize($array_serial);
get_menu_list($array_unserial);
?>
```

All index "otitle" of this array is being displayed in a form in an input type text.

**How can the user modify and save the array with just one submit (or any other way) ??**

And the array is dynamic, and can be much bigger.

Comment: This code could be made a lot more elegant by using recursion instead of stacking for loops.

Comment: I din't knew about recursion, before i wrote this code. I am still using this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/cc1j-n3t8).

This should get you most of the way there. The important part here is to specify the ID in the array you want to update for each child item, so that the structure is recreated on submit. This can be achieved through a `otitle[<id1>][children][<id2>][children]...[<id5>][name]` style.

If you submit the form in the fiddle above, the array structure generated by PHP from the form is displayed at the top of the page. From that, you should be able to iterate the array and its children and grab the updated values.

```
//Here is my code to view "otitle" in a input type
function get_menu_list($selected_menus)
{
    if($selected_menus != null){
        foreach($selected_menus as $id1=>$menu_level_1)
        {
            $title = implode("///",$menu_level_1['id']);
            echo '
                <li class="dd-item">
                <div class="dd-handle">
                <input type="text" name="otitle['.$id1.'][name]" value="'.$menu_level_1['id']['otitle'].'" />
                </div>';
            if(isset($menu_level_1['children']))
            {
                echo '<ol class="dd-list">';
                foreach($menu_level_1['children'] as $id2=>$menu_level_2)
                {
                    $title_level_2 = implode("///",$menu_level_2['id']);
                    echo '
                        <li class="dd-item">
                        <div class="dd-handle">
                        <input type="text" name="otitle['.$id1.'][children]['.$id2.'][name]" value="'.$menu_level_2['id']['otitle'].'" />
                        </div>';
                    if(isset($menu_level_2['children']))
                    {
                        echo '<ol class="dd-list">';
                        foreach($menu_level_2['children'] as $id3=>$menu_level_3)
                        {
                            $title_level_3 = implode("///",$menu_level_3['id']);
                            echo '
                                <li class="dd-item">
                                <div class="dd-handle">
                                <input type="text" name="otitle['.$id1.'][children]['.$id2.'][children]['.$id3.'][name]" value="'.$menu_level_3['id']['otitle'].'" />
                                </div>';
                            if(isset($menu_level_3['children']))
                            {
                                echo '<ol class="dd-list">';
                                foreach($menu_level_3['children'] as $id4=>$menu_level_4)
                                {
                                    $title_level_4 = implode("///",$menu_level_4['id']);
                                    echo '
                                        <li class="dd-item">
                                        <div class="dd-handle">
                                        <input type="text" name="otitle['.$id1.'][children]['.$id2.'][children]['.$id3.'][children]['.$id4.'][name]" value="'.$menu_level_4['id']['otitle'].'" />
                                        </div>';
                                    if(isset($menu_level_4['children']))
                                    {
                                        echo '<ol class="dd-list">';
                                        foreach($menu_level_4['children'] as $id5=>$menu_level_5)
                                        {
                                            $title_level_5 = implode("///",$menu_level_5['id']);
                                            echo '
                                                <li class="dd-item">
                                                <div class="dd-handle">
                                                <input type="text" name="otitle['.$id1.'][children]['.$id2.'][children]['.$id3.'][children]['.$id4.'][children]['.$id5.'][name]" value="'.$menu_level_5['id']['otitle'].'" />
                                                </div>
                                                </li>';
                                        }
                                        echo "</ol>";
                                    }
                                    echo '</li>';
                                }
                                echo "</ol>";
                            }
                            echo '</li>';
                        }
                        echo "</ol>";
                    }
                    echo '</li>';
                }
                echo '</ol>';
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }//end if
    else
        return null;    
}
$array_unserial = unserialize($array_serial);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, passed other values of array in hidden. Placed all values of array in common input name. And put index "id" (that was missing). And the problem was solved.